# What’s this little icon mean in the iPhone call log?

Tags: ios

This is my call log , this icon is next to an incoming call from a number not saved in my phone but I’ve never seen this before.

[image: ios tty symbol - phone handset with rows of keyboard keys below]

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

That is the TTY teletype symbol.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201906

> Teletype (TTY) machines are used by people who are deaf or hard of hearing to communicate by typing and reading text.